# Web application with backbone.js and requirejs packages, requirejs optimizer

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, js-amd

I'm very grateful for Addy Osmani and Thomas Davis for publishing their examples and boilerplates 
(http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules, https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-aura).

They were helping me a lot to get starting.

I'm currently developing a large web application. So I have a lot of components, for instance address management, date management, todos. Each component fills the whole space in my app (with the exception of the menu bar). Each selection of a new component in the menu requires a page transition.

In the beginning I took the file structure, boilerplate used by the tutorials above (giving all views to the 'views' directory). But as more components were added, putting alle views into one views directory became confusing for me. Even making subdirectories would be no solution, because in this file structure I lost the information which view is related to which model.

So I searched for another solution and found requirejs amd packages (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#packages).
This helped me alot since all modules belonging to the same component (models, collections, views) came into one directory. Because postfixing every model with "Model" (and so on), things where clean enough for me.

Now to the question:
I'm in the pre-production stage. I did not get into building and concatenation things together for production deployment. But now I want to try the requirejs optimizer.
I have read the page "http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html" from James Burke. But not everything is clear to me.

Want I want is the following: I have these package directories. All the amd modules (views, models, collections) from one package directory shall be concatenated to one file, but their dependencies should not be included, as a lot of these outside package dependencies are loaded separately in the beginning.

Is there anybody with the same or similar requirements, who has already taken this step and can give some hints.

Thanks a lot
Wolfgang

Comment: I just released an open source toolkit which will hopefully help others as much as it helps me. It is a composition of many open source tools which gives you a working requirejs backbone app out of the box.

It provides single commands to run: dev web server, jasmine single browser test runner, jasmine js-test-driver multi browser test runner, and concatenization/minification for JavaScript and CSS. It also outputs an unminified version of your app for production debugging, precompiles your handlebar templates, and supports i18n.

It just works.

http://github.com/davidjnelson/agilejs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can take a look at these couple of boilerplates and see if they are helpful...

https://github.com/jcreamer898/RequireJS-Backbone-Starter
https://github.com/david0178418/BackboneJS-AMD-Boilerplate
https://github.com/swbiggart/node-express-requirejs-backbone

A few of those have build scripts in them to show you how that works.

Comment: Thanks for that, could you tell us which boilerplates you used and why?

Comment: I wrote the first one, It has the build script in it as well as some actual AMD forks of Backbone and Underscore so there is no need to use the loaders that the second one uses. The third one is an example that uses Node as the server.

Comment: could you please add a link to that AMD fork? I can't find it.

Comment: There are a few here... https://github.com/amdjs